# Output CSV using Powershell

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I got a problem with understanding of output CSV file from powershell script!

I have a Request to restapi server and I'm getting a variable which contain 10 or more lines, like:

```
>$ExpenseDescription 
Taxi to airport
Taxi to seaport
Taxi to spaceport
Taxi to home
```

And the I'm creating table

```
$tableExpenses=@"
Created On | Description | Expense Category
$ExpenseCreatedOnt | $ExpenseDescription |$ExpenseReport
$tableExpense|Out-File C:\Users\book.xls
$tableExpense|Out-File C:\Users\book.csv
```

And as output file I'm getting *.xls* and *.csv*!

So the problem is that I have 10 lines in variable `$ExpenseDescription`and the OutFile contain all 10 lines in 1 cell in *book.xls*!

How can I split them in code and make OutFile in format like this:

```
Created On | Description   | Expense Category
 10.10.2018|Taxi to airport| Money
 11.10.2018|Taxi to seaport| Visa
```

Because now I'm having this in output

```
Created On | Description   | Expense Category
10.10.2018 11.10.2018|Taxi to airport Taxi to seaport| Money Visa|
```

OK, I'll add more code)

## WebRequest

`$ReportURI = ("https://api.rest.com/data/query")
$ReportQuery = 
@{"q"="SELECT Category,Description,CreatedOn from Expense"}`
`Try
{$ResponseReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $ReportURI -Headers @{"Authorization" = $SessionId} -Body ( $ReportQuery | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop}
 Write-Host $ResponseReport}
ConvertTo-Json $ResponseReport`

## variables

`$ExpenseCreatedOn = $ResponseReport.CreatedOn
$ExpenseDescription = $ResponseReport.Description
$ExpenseReport = $ResponseReport.Category.Name`

## table_format

`$tableExpense=@"
Created On Description Expense Category
$ExpenseCreatedOn $ExpenseDescription $ExpenseReport`

`$tableExpense|Out-File C:\Users\book.xls
$tableExpense|Out-File C:\Users\book.csv`

Comment: We probably need to see more of your code. I can't really understand exactly what you are dooing from what you have provided.

Comment: I'added more code for better understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not outputting a CSV. With `Out-File`, you're exporting a text file.

Providing that your variables hold an array of strings, you could index into them to create an object, then use `Export-Csv` to export that:

```
foreach($i in 0..($ExpenseDescription.Count - 1)){

    [array]$tableExpenses += [pscustomobject]@{
        "Created On"       = $ExpenseCreatedOnt[$i]
        Description        = $ExpenseDescription[$i]
        "Expense Category" = $ExpenseReport[$i]
    }

}

$tableExpenses | Export-Csv C:\Users\book.csv -NoType
$tableExpenses | Export-Csv C:\Users\book2.csv -NoType -Delimiter "|"
```

Comment: Thank you @gms0ulman
That was helpfull , but I stil have problem with Delimeter in csv output,I was able to add  `"t"` in column headers so I have 3 columns, but the other data is exporting in format like :

`Created On | Description   | Expense Category`

`10.10.2018 Taxi to airport Money|`

And looks like all data output is in first column,
and I'm not fully understanding why it's happening!

Comment: @JodieCambo By default, `Export-Csv` uses comma (`,`) as the delimiter. It appears you want to use pipe (`|`)? I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: Thanks again, I did it much harder, created `variable $tab='t`
and added it 
`Description= $tab+$ExpenseDescription[$i]` so it works on every line, 
For sure your method is quite easier and correct!
So Thank you!